# Why does ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 slow down a MySQL query so much?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query that looks very simple. However, if I combine ORDER BY and LIMIT, the performance goes down by scales. I found several questions about limited performance of MySQL in large tables, but I do not think that this is the cuase here, because without any LIMIT the query works find.

Here are the queries in increasing "complexity"

```
SELECT * FROM `mydata`.`mytable` WHERE ((token='XFRA1NMDU9XY') AND (section=210874));
/* Rows: 0  Time: 0,094 sec. */
SELECT * FROM `mydata`.`mytable` WHERE ((token='XFRA1NMDU9XY') AND (section=210874)) LIMIT 1;
/* Rows: 0  Time: 0,063 sec. */
SELECT * FROM `mydata`.`mytable` WHERE ((token='XFRA1NMDU9XY') AND (section=210874)) ORDER BY mailing;
/* Rows: 0  Time: 0,125 sec. */
SELECT * FROM `mydata`.`mytable` WHERE ((token='XFRA1NMDU9XY') AND (section=210874)) ORDER BY mailing LIMIT 1;
/* Rows: 0  Time: 45,500 sec. */
```

Note the significant increase in query time in the last row. This is no outlier but was replicated several times. I actually had query times of 3 minutes and more for this query, while everything else worked fine.

Here are some data:

- The table has ~2.000.000 entries
- There are ~5.000 entries WHERE (section=210874)
- The database runs on MySQL 8.0.20 and Ubuntu 20.04
- It is a InnoDB table, there is an index for `section` (and others), but not for `token`

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `data` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'ascii_bin',
    `mailing` INT(10,0) NOT NULL,
    `token` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'ascii_bin',
    `section` INT(10,0) NOT NULL,
    `expiry` INT(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`data`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `mailing_CS` (`mailing`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `section_CS` (`section`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `mailing_CS` FOREIGN KEY (`mailing`) REFERENCES `mydata`.`mailings` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `section_CS` FOREIGN KEY (`section`) REFERENCES `mydata`.`sections` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='ascii_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Any idea why the combination of ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 has this effect? `EXPPLAIN` tells me that different keys (indices) are used for the former (`section_CS`) and the last query (`mailing_CS`).

I can, of course, just leave the `LIMIT 1` out, because there will be no, one or few rows per `token`. But I would like to understand the underlying problem.

Comment: explain your sql string

Comment: I cannot see the EXPLAIN

Comment: What client (commandline, workbench, phpmyadmin, etc) are you using to get the timings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think MySQL is trying to use `mailing_CS` index in last query and this index is not optimal.

Try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mydata`.`mytable` USE INDEX (section_CS) IGNORE INDEX(mailing_CS) 
WHERE (
    (token = 'XFRA1NMDU9XY') AND 
    (section = 210874)
) 
ORDER BY mailing 
LIMIT 1
```

Also you may use composite index (section, mailing) for this table.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL ORDER BY with LIMIT is the most common use of ORDER BY in interactive applications with large data sets being sorted..

---

Make sure it uses **index**. It is very important to have ORDER BY with LIMIT executed without scanning and sorting full result set, so it is important for it to use index – in this case, index range scan will be started and query execution stopped as soon as required amount of rows generated.

---

For example, if I do SELECT * FROM sites ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 10; I would use index on (date_created) to get a result set very fast.

---

Now what if I have something like SELECT * FROM sites WHERE category_id=5 ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 10;

In this case index by date_created may also work but it might not be the most efficient – If it is a rare category large portion of table may be scanned to find 10 rows. So index on (category_id, date_created) will be a better idea.

---

Indexing may help you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ((token='XFRA1NMDU9XY')
  AND (section=210874))
ORDER BY mailing LIMIT 1;
```

Needs either of these composite indexes:

```
INDEX(token, section, mailing)
INDEX(section, token, mailing)
```

Any shorter indexes (leftmost column(s) matching) should be removed to avoid confusion.

As for why you got those timings...

The first two -- `WHERE a=1 AND b=2` -- would use either `INDEX(a)` or `INDEX(b)`, but have to scan to check the other of value.  So even switching to `INDEX(a,b)` or `(b,a)` would have sped them up.

For the 3rd query -- `WHERE a=1 AND b=2 ORDER BY c` -- is a puzzle; it should have taken longer than the 4th.

`ORDER BY`, without a suitable index, requires the following:

1. Gather all the potential rows (thousands?)
2. Sort them.
3. Finally peel of one row (`LIMIT 1`)

With either of my indexes, the 4th query should be on the order of a millisecond.